# Replacement of cv::imencode

Tags: opencv

I wonder if there is some replacement of cv::imencode function without a need of OpenCV. I'd like to have that still under python.
Can please advice how to replace it without using OpenCV?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use libjpeg to encode jpeg, libtiff to encode tiff, libpng to encode png etc.

Comment: how this  std::vector<unsigned char> buf; cv::Mat frame = cv::Mat(im1D, im2D, CV_8UC3, image); cv::imencode(".jpg", frame , buf); gonna be replaced by e.g. jpeg4py?

Comment: I didn't recommend jpeg4py (that one doesn't even have encode function). I recommended to use libjpeg directly. If you need to know how to import native libraries into python - use search on stackoverflow. As if for documentation you can direct to libjpeg official documentation (which can be nasty) or variety of blogs which help with using that.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can take a look on my https://github.com/lilohuang/PyTurboJPEG which is a Python wrapper of libjpeg-turbo for decoding and encoding JPEG image without using OpenCV.